# In the train method what's the relationship between tuneGrid and trControl?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, r-caret, training-data

The preferred method in R to train known ML models is to use the `caret` package and its generic `train` method. My question is what's the relationship between the `tuneGrid` and `trControl` parameters? as they are undoubtedly related and I can't figure out their relationship by reading the documentation ... for example:

```
library(caret)  
# train and choose best model using cross validation
df <- ... # contains input data
control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, p = .9, allowParallel = TRUE)
fit <- train(y ~ ., method = "knn", 
             data = df,
             tuneGrid = data.frame(k = seq(9, 71, 2)),
             trControl = control)
```

If I run the code above what's happening? how do the 10 CV folds each containing 90% of the data as per the `trainControl` definition are combined with the 32 levels of `k`?

More concretely:

- I have 32 levels for the parameter `k`.
- I also have 10 CV folds.

Is the k-nearest neighbors model trained 32*10 times? or otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You partition your training data into 10 sets, say 1..10. Starting with set 1, you train your model using all of 2..10 (90% of the training data) and test it on set 1. This is repeated again for set2, set3.. It's a total of 10 times, and you have 32 values of k to test, hence 32 * 10 = 320.

You can also pull out this cv results using the returnResamp function in trainControl. I simplify it to 3-fold and 4 values of k below:

```
df <- mtcars
set.seed(100)
control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3, p = .9,returnResamp="all")
fit <- train(mpg  ~ ., method = "knn", 
             data = mtcars,
             tuneGrid = data.frame(k = 2:5),
             trControl = control)

resample_results = fit$resample
resample_results
       RMSE  Rsquared      MAE k Resample
1  3.502321 0.7772086 2.483333 2    Fold1
2  3.807011 0.7636239 2.861111 3    Fold1
3  3.592665 0.8035741 2.697917 4    Fold1
4  3.682105 0.8486331 2.741667 5    Fold1
5  2.473611 0.8665093 1.995000 2    Fold2
6  2.673429 0.8128622 2.210000 3    Fold2
7  2.983224 0.7120910 2.645000 4    Fold2
8  2.998199 0.7207914 2.608000 5    Fold2
9  2.094039 0.9620830 1.610000 2    Fold3
10 2.551035 0.8717981 2.113333 3    Fold3
11 2.893192 0.8324555 2.482500 4    Fold3
12 2.806870 0.8700533 2.368333 5    Fold3

# we manually calculate the mean RMSE for each parameter
tapply(resample_results$RMSE,resample_results$k,mean)
       2        3        4        5 
2.689990 3.010492 3.156360 3.162392

# and we can see it corresponds to the final fit result
fit$results
k     RMSE  Rsquared      MAE    RMSESD RsquaredSD     MAESD
1 2 2.689990 0.8686003 2.029444 0.7286489 0.09245494 0.4376844
2 3 3.010492 0.8160947 2.394815 0.6925154 0.05415954 0.4067066
3 4 3.156360 0.7827069 2.608472 0.3805227 0.06283697 0.1122577
4 5 3.162392 0.8131593 2.572667 0.4601396 0.08070670 0.1891581
```